# How to manage relation in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB.I have one Master Collection user_group.The sample document is shown bellow.

`{group_name:"xyz","previlege":["Add","Delete"],...}`

And second collection user_detail

```
{"user_name":"pt123","group_name":"xyz",...}
```

How can I maintain relation between these two collections.Should I use reference from user_group into user_detail or any other alternative?

Comment: What is your backend stack? Java? Python? What libraries? etc.

Comment: My backend stack is java

Comment: Lots of good stuff here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/

Answer (score 3):

Often, in MongoDB, the "has many" relationship is managed on the opposite side as in a relational database.  A MongoDB document often will have an array of ObjectIds or group names (or whatever you're using to identify the foreign document). This is opposed to a relational database where the other side usually has a "belongs to" column.

Do be clear, this is not required.  In your example, you could store an array of user details IDs in your group document if it was the most common query that you were going to make. Basically, the question you should ask is "what query am I likely to need?" and design your documents to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: You don't.
The entire design philosophy changes when you start looking at MongoDB. If I were you, I would maintain the `previlege` field inside the user_detail documents itself.

```
{"user_name":"abc","group_name":"xyz","previlege" : ["add","delete"]}
```

This may not be ideal if you keep changing group priviledges though. But the idea is, you make design your data storage in a way so that all the information for one "record" can be stored in one object.

Comment: I am agree with you,but I am managing the user_group and hence need to update group previleges frequently.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB being NoSQL does not have explicit joins. Workarounds are possible, but not recommended(read MapReduce).

Your best bet is to retrieve both the documents from the mongo collections on the client side and apply user specific privileges. Make sure you have index on the group_name in the user_group collection.

Or better still store the permissions[read, del, etc] for the user in the same document after applying the join at the client side. But then, you cannot update the collection externally since this might break invariants. Everytime an update to the user group occurs, you will need to apply those permissions(privileges) yourself at the client side and save those privileges in the same document. Writes might suffer but reads will be fast(assuming a few fields are indexed, like username).

Comment: Using MR to do joins is just wrong...you should do them client side

Comment: that's what i said in the 2nd para.